# Not all values are being returned from MS Graph in an SPFx web part in SharePoint Online

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am writing an SPFx web part for SharePoint Online which displays members of a team.
However some information for the users is not being returned.

```
var client = await this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3');
        
var result;

//this works 
result = await client.api('groups/' + this.properties.groupGUID + '/members').get();
//this gives an error ...
**//Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')**
result = await client.api('groups/' + this.properties.groupGUID + '/members').select("id,displayName,onPremisesSamAccountName,jobTitle").get();
```

When I do get results (with the first result assignment, above) I get no result for some values

Thanks
P

```
console.log('1-' + result.value[index].city);
          console.log('2-' + result.value[index].companyName);
          console.log('3-' + result.value[index].country);
          console.log('4-' + result.value[index].department);
          console.log('5-' + result.value[index].displayName);
          console.log('6-' + result.value[index].givenName);
          console.log('7-' + result.value[index].id);
          console.log('8-' + result.value[index].jobTitle);
          console.log('9-' + result.value[index].mail);
          console.log('10-' + result.value[index].mailNickname);
          console.log('11-' + result.value[index].mobilePhone);
          console.log('12-' + result.value[index].officeLocation);
          console.log('13-' + result.value[index].postalCode);
          console.log('14-' + result.value[index].surname);
          console.log('15-' + result.value[index].telephoneNumber);
          console.log('16-' + result.value[index].userPrincipalName);
          console.log('17-' + result.value[index].accountEnabled);
          console.log('18-' + result.value[index].onPremisesSamAccountName);

1-undefined
2-undefined
3-undefined
4-undefined
5-Bloggs, Joe
6-Joe
7-1111111-111-etc-etc
8-The Big Cheese
9-Joe.Bloggs@clueless.com
10-undefined
11-+6969420
12-Floor 1
13-undefined
14-Bloggs
15-undefined
16-Joe.Bloggs@clueless.com
17-undefined
18-undefined
```

Comment: What permissions did you set? User.Read.All, Directory.Read.All should be enough

Answer (score 0):

When you are using "select" in a graph api call you have to specify every property you want. You can read the api here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#select-parameter

So your first call is getting the default properties for an user like defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0 (search for "returned by default"). So for example *onPremisesSamAccountName* is not returned.

[image]

Your second call is just returning the properties you selected.

So the result will look like this

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects(id,displayName,onPremisesSamAccountName,jobTitle)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "33db0872-...",
            "displayName": "XY",
            "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
            "jobTitle": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Where your "toString" error is coming from I do not know. Maybe because your index was wrong? Or you did something specific after receiving the members which you did not include in your posted code. The code you posted is correct so far. The select is working as it should.